# Additional kwargs for router in @list_route decorator REST framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Consider this model:

```
def Vote(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    target = models.ForeignKey(Player)
```

Now, I have a ViewSet:

```
class VoteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Vote.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VoteSerializer
```

and I register a router:

```
api_router = routers.SimpleRouter()
api_router.register(r'votes', VoteViewSet)
```

This way I can access resources like:

```
http://example.com/api/votes             # lists all votes
http://example.com/api/votes/1/          # return vote with pk=1
```

How can I create a route which returns all votes given and received by a player using a url like

```
http://example.com/api/votes/players/1/   # ?
```

I would try to do something like this, but...

```
class VoteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     queryset = Vote.objects.all()
     serializer_class = VoteSerializer

     @detail_route()
     def players(self, request):
         # Here I need to access player id in the url!
```

Comment: not an answer, but a better url for what you want would be `http://example.com/api/players/1/votes/`

Comment: That's what I thought after I posted the question (and this way it works), but I'd like to find an answer to the abstract problem.

Comment: have a look here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis/

Answer (score 1):

You can define the `lookup_field` attribute on the viewset so that it filters the Vote queryset by the player_id field.

```
class PlayerVotesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Vote.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VoteSerializer
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'player_id'
    lookup_field = 'player_id'
```

Then in your router you should define the path as:

```
api_router.register(r'votes/players', PlayerVotesViewSet)
```

Comment: Thanks. It's important to note that the kwarg from `lookup_url_kwarg` is *automatically* added after the prefix. So registering something like `api_router.register(r'votes/players/<str:player_id>', PlayerVotesViewSet)` won't work.